# Could there be some safe, hypothetical way of turning on and of thermoregulation?

Tags: metabolism, neuroanatomy

This is something I thought of with the whole artificial gill concept.  Could a modification to the brain/nervous system allow a human to turn off their thermoregulation in air/water of the right temperature range, so they wouldn't have to expend as much oxygen?